# XCode 8, cannot receive push notification

Tags: push-notification, xcode8

After upgrade to XCode 8, my iphone with IOS 10 cannot receive push notification any more.

- I have enable the "Automatically manage signing".
- I re-generate the certificate from Apple website, the universal one.
- My local codes is running without any error.
- I can get device token correctly with the codes (swift 3):
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  ```
  print("start didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
  // Register the supported interaction types.
  let types = UIUserNotificationType([.alert, .badge, .sound])
  let mySettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: types, categories: nil)
  UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(mySettings)

  // Register for remote notifications.
  UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

  return true
  ```

  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

  ```
  print("start didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")

  let deviceTokenString = ((deviceToken as NSData).description.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "<>")) as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
  ....
  ```

  }

My PHP in server side always return 200 which is successful.
    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
        define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
    $pem_file     = '/var/my.pem';
    $pem_secret   = 'xxxxxx';
    $apns_topic   = 'xxxxxx';
    $apns_expiration = 2;

```
$change_alert = "{
                    \"aps\": {
                            \"alert\": \"$alert_message\",
                            \"badge\": $badge,
                            \"sound\": \"default\"
                    },
                    \"xxxxxxxx\": \"$xxxxxx\"
                 }";
$url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";
//$url = "https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $change_alert);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("apns-topic: $apns_topic", "apns-expiration: $apns_expiration"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

- My apns-topic is the same with my app bundle id.

Any idea for this issue?

BTW, XCode 8 is not as stable as the previous version.

===============
CURL logs:

```
*   Trying 17.188.135.156...
* Connected to api.push.apple.com (17.188.135.156) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=api.push.apple.com; OU=management:idms.group.533599; O=Apple Inc.; ST=California; C=US
*  start date: Aug 28 19:03:46 2015 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 26 19:03:46 2017 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.push.apple.com" matched cert's "api.push.apple.com"
*  issuer: CN=Apple IST CA 2 - G1; OU=Certification Authority; O=Apple Inc.; C=US
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7f2d6eda3970)
> POST /3/device/3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.push.apple.com
Accept: */*
apns-topic: xxxxxxxxxx
apns-expiration: 0
Content-Length: 316
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2.0 200
< apns-id:AF034xxxxxxxxxxxx0F9F27
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.push.apple.com left intact
```